# Regex to match URLs with files not in the root or one specified folder

Tags: regex

I'm trying to come up with a regular expression that will match on all folders on a website except for files that are in the root folder or one specific folder that I specify.

I'm working in a restricting GUI environment that implements it in Javascript/PERL so there are some considerations:

- It's not important that I match on the entire URL, just a portion of it.
- \K is not supported
- I can't use the results of groupings

Here are some examples:

#### Don't match on files in the root directory OR files in one specified folder, like:

- example.com/index.html
- example.com/dontmatchonme/

#### Match on all other files/folders:

- example.com/matchonthisfolder/test
- example.com/matchonanyotherfolder/index.html

---

I can use example.com/(?!dontmatchonme/) to match on everything that is not in this specific folder but then I lose my matches on any files in the root folder (which I want to keep).

I really appreciate any advice or techniques that could help me solve this issue in one regular expression.

Comment: This is not a task for RegEx.

Comment: @Godisgood I realize that this would be better solved programmatically but unfortunately this is not possible in my environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^example.com\/(?!dontmatchonme\/).*\/
```

- `^example.com` matches the "site root"
- `(?!dontmatchonme\/)` is a zero width negative lookahead assertion to not match "dontmatchonme"
- `.*\/` ensures that the rest of the path has an extra `/` in it, which shows that it is not in the root folder

In this example I have escaped `/` characters with a backslash `\` because that's the way it works in perl.  You will probably need to omit this